# Setting Spin angle in 2.8

Tags: edit-mode

I use the `Edit Mode` > `Spin` feature to get rotated shapes from the basic shapes I create. Sadly, when I `Spin` manually, it goes beyond 360 degrees. There is no way to confirm that the `Spin` is 360 degree when doing it manually. I wanted to ask whether it is possible to set an angle for `Spin` so that the `Spin` is perfectly 360 degrees or the set value. Thanks.

Comment: You can write in the angle manually in that little toolbox that appears in the bottom left after you do a spin operation, is that what you're talking about? Or are you looking to change the "precision" spin snapping degrees away from the default of 5 and make it 360 instead?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. How do we make the steps vanish and make them smooth ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "vanish", but you can change the number of steps if you press N and select the Tool tab on the right side of the box that pops up in the top right.

Comment: Found that. Thanks. I tried to use " shade smooth " under " object " menu. Sadly the whole texture gets distorted. The no. of steps was very helpful. I found out when I tried the box as you suggested

Comment: Yes you can select the object and then press R to rotate it. Then just type the angle you want.